# Is this a known thread safe syched/locked pattern?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, c#-4.0, thread-safety

I feel like I'm re-inventing the wheel, and that there is a good chance that someone out there already banged his head against the code and came up with a good, stable and tested pattern that solve this problem, and I haven't encountered it yet.

I've come up with the following solution that seems to work for me right now.
It is supposed to provide a consistent interface to working with objects that should be accessed in a thread-safe manner.

[@pst](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11166073/is-this-a-known-thread-safe-syched-locked-pattern#comment14645626_11166073) has called this an *"Atomic" object get/set holder*, is this a pattern that's used elsewhere?

Here is the interface:

```
public interface ISynched<T>
{
    bool Read( ref T value );
    bool Read( ref T value, TimeSpan timeout );

    bool Write( T value );
    bool Write( T value, TimeSpan timeout );

    bool Do( Action<T> roAction );
    bool Do( Action<T> roAction, TimeSpan timeout );
    bool Do( Action<T, Action<T>> rwAction );
    bool Do( Action<T, Action<T>> rwAction, TimeSpan timeout );
}
```

The implementation is as follows:

```
public class Synched<T>: ISynched<T>
{
    static public readonly TimeSpan Infinity = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(-1);

    private T _value;

    public static Synched<T> MakeSynched( T value )
    {
        return new Synched<T>() { _value = value };
    }

    private Synched() {}

    public bool Read( ref T value )
    {
        return Read( ref value, Infinity );
    }
    public bool Read( ref T value, TimeSpan timeout )
    {
        var tmp = default(T);
        var success = Do( (v) => tmp = v, timeout );
        if( success ) value = tmp;
        return success;
    }

    public bool Write( T value )
    {
        return Do( (v, set) => set(v) );
    }
    public bool Write( T value, TimeSpan timeout )
    {
        return Do( (v, set) => set(v), timeout );
    }

    public bool Do( Action<T> roAction )
    {
        return Do( roAction, Infinity );
    }
    public bool Do( Action<T> roAction, TimeSpan timeout )
    {
        bool lockWasTaken = false;
        try
        {
            Monitor.TryEnter(this, timeout, ref lockWasTaken);
            if(!lockWasTaken) return false;

            roAction( _value );
            return true;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (lockWasTaken) Monitor.Exit(this);
        }
    }

    public bool Do( Action<T, Action<T>> rwAction )
    {
        return Do( rwAction, Infinity);
    }
    public bool Do( Action<T, Action<T>> rwAction, TimeSpan timeout )
    {
        bool lockWasTaken = false;
        try
        {
            Monitor.TryEnter(this, timeout, ref lockWasTaken);
            if(!lockWasTaken) return false;

            rwAction( _value, value => _value = value );
            return true;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (lockWasTaken) Monitor.Exit(this);
        }
    }
}
```

And an additional static non generic class to make it easier to code Synched object creation:

```
public static class Synched
{
    public static Synched<T> MakeSynched<T>( T value )
    {
        return Synched<T>.MakeSynched( value );
    }
}
```

Edited: I've changed the example to make more sense
A sample use case would look like this (the code doesn't mean anything, just an example (a bad one at that):

```
var synchedCol = Synched.MakeSynched( new List<SomeClass>() );

synchedCol.Do( c => {
    c.Add(new SomeClass());
    c.Add(new SomeClass() { Property1 = "something" } );
} );

var i = 1;
SomeClass val;
synchedCol.Do( c => val = c[i] );

var i = 1;
synchedCol.Do( c => {
    if( c[i].Property1 == "something" )
    {
        c.Remove(c[i]);
    }
});
```

So am I on the right tracks? Has anyone encountered anything similar? Are there any existing patterns out there that are similar?

Comment: In a nutshell... what's the question/task? I'm not quite sure how it (is supposed to) adds thread-safety... just an "Atomic" object get/set holder?

Comment: Also, why would you need to make immutable types such as `bool` and `TimeSpan` "thread safe"?

Comment: The `Do` methods violate the guideline that a method should not call external code (i.e., code that is not under its control) while holding a lock.

Comment: Also, this is effectively calling `lock(this)` to handle the synchronization - locking on a private object would be much safer...

Comment: @pst you are basically right, can you point me to other examples?

Comment: [@KirkWoll](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11166073/is-this-a-known-thread-safe-syched-locked-pattern#comment14645674_11166073) - thanks, I replaced the examples to make a bit more sense

Comment: [@dtb](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11166073/is-this-a-known-thread-safe-syched-locked-pattern#comment14645837_11166073) - Not exactly, since it's meant to be used by specific lambda code, I am trying to use a construct that will replace code syntax, so although it's run 'outside' of it's control, it seems like a legitimate construct.

Comment: [@ReedCopsey](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11166073/is-this-a-known-thread-safe-syched-locked-pattern#comment14645850_11166073) - I thought about this alot myself - usually you are right, but in this case this was created specifically to manage the `lock`, so although it's *usually* not recommended, it seems like this might be the only case where it is legitimate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Do not try to reinvent the wheel*

If you want a thread-safe collection pick one from **[System.Collections.Concurrent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent.aspx)** namespace.

For example `BlockingColletion<T>` provides blocking and bounding capabilities for thread-safe collections that implement `IProducerConsumerCollection<T>`. This will be much more performant than your implementation since it implements producer/consumer(reader/writer) pattern. It means that reader do not have to be synchronized and won't block each other.

Comment: this is exactly the stuff I'm looking for, however, the List was just an example, I am more interested in the producer/consumer(reader/writer) pattern you've mentioned. If I get references to these and they answer my needs, I'll edit your answer and accept it. Thanks!

Comment: if the list is just an example, on what do you want more information?

Comment: The code itself is a generic pattern for atomic operations, basically a syntax that hides some of the mechanics of locking.
I've just now reviewed what @Jakub suggested, and for a list, that's perfect.
I'm just looking for more producer/consumer pattern info to link to this answer before selecting it as the answer

Answer (score 0):

Depending upon what you are doing, I would suggest that a good pattern would be to have a method which accepts a `Func<T,T>` which should--given the existing value of the data item, produce a new value; the caller must be prepared for the possibility that the delegate may be called more than once if the underlying data item gets written while it's executing.  For example, two callers try to update the same data item (initially 5) with a `Func<int,int>` that computes `(x) => x+1`, it's possible both delegates would be called with a value of 5 (computing 6), one update would succeed, and the other would re-call its delegate with a value of 6 (computing 7) and then store that result.

When contention is not severe, that approach is relatively easy to make work correctly *if the caller is prepared to have the function called multiple times*.  If the function takes very long to compute, however, and if there is much contention for the resource, a straightforward approach can be somewhat slow.  Its performance can be made somewhat reasonable, however, by having code which detect contention and start using monitor objects to implement "timed advisory locks": if an item's new value is being computed by one client's delegate, allowing another client to access that item will cause the work done by either the pending client or the new client to be wasted.  Depending upon how long the pending client's function has been running, it's possible that its efforts might never amount to anything anyway, so having its actions be invalidated may be no real loss.  On the other hand, one could have logic so that if the total time which new clients have been waiting for a resource gets to be sufficiently large relative to the time which a client's function has been running, one could serve all the new clients before letting that slow function try again.